# I don't see bottom bar buttons...(using Xcode 5.1.1)

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

So I was editing a project of mine today, and I when I was running it I suddenly realized that the bottom bar buttons don't show at all. It used to in previous builds. I even put together a simple example and ran the product in the simulator -- no bottom bar buttons or bottom bar!!! Here's what I want to see:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10838242/xcodestoryboard.png

But that bottom bar doesn't show.

What's going on here?  I even set the view's bottom bar to "opaque toolbar." It just doesn't show. Using Xcode 5.1.1 -- is this an issue with this version of Xcode?

Here's the super-simple project:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10838242/Test2.zip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the "super-simple" project, it's because your navigation controller's Shows Toolbar is turned off (in the storyboard).

[image]

Check that checkbox and run the project; the bottom bar will now appear (I tried it so I know it works!).

Comment: By the way, in the "super-simple" project, the STViewController is non-functional (i.e. there are no instances of it in your storyboard). Just saying.

Comment: Thanks. I guess for whatever reason that option wasn't enabled in the normal project (non-simple example). I haven't touched that one in a while, and all of the sudden that problem appears. Maybe it was after I an xcode update or something I accidentally did. Also, I just have the STViewController in the simple version because xcode generated them; didn't intend on customizing the project too much for this post.

Comment: So it turns out some of the views don't need a toolbar because of tabbed view. I'll have to fix the storyboard to enforce that dichotomy.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on Matt's post (which is correct), but in addition to his "Shows Toolbar" toggle, you can specify what kind of toolbar you want in the app from the navigation controller in the storyboard (i.e. opaque toolbar, translucent toolbar, translucent black tab bar, etc).

Comment: Yeah that's true. I may just stick with stock functionality.